# How to nest data in Firebase Realtime database (Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database in Firebase currently looks like this:

```
locations: {
    person: ""
    location: ""
}
```

How do I nest the data so that it looks something like this:

```
locations: {
    person: "" {
        location: ""
}
}
```

A structure where locations is the parent, person is the child, and location is the child of person.

I know the relationships, I just am not too sure of the syntax.

Here is the code I currently have, written in Swift:

```
let locRef = locationRef.childByAutoId()
let locItem = [
    "location": getLocation(),
    "person": senderId
]

locRef.setValue(locItem)
```

Thanks.

Comment: The bigger question is why do you want to structure the data in that fashion. Typically, you would have locations/loc_id_01 and locations/loc_id_02 etc and then within each location have info about that location. There may be an opportunity to denormalize your data to provide a flatter structure in this case. Maybe not?

Comment: I feel like fashioning data this way would make it much easier to retrieve that data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let locRef = locationRef.childByAutoId()
let locItem = [
    senderId : [
        "location": getLocationID()
    ]
]
```

SenderID will be the key for the person, so you can find the Person by its ID... And the ID is holding a nested location key

Do you only need the logic? Or do you need working code example?

Comment: Thanks! Makes a lot of sense

Comment: Alright... If you have further questions, just write me a followup

Comment: It worked! Now how would I retrieve just the location of the senderID from Firebase?

Comment: You have the userID as key, so you can easily retrieve it by asking locations.[userID].location

Comment: Cool but isn't there fire base specific syntax for retrieving data?

Comment: Yes you could retrieve it by url... Thats exactly how you would do it with the sdk... Just Open your Browser and navigate to <yourfirebaseaccount>/location/userid/location... This will send you the Location

Comment: I have no idea how to do what you recommended in the above comment in terms of syntax haha :( this is what I have so far referring to the Firebase docs for retrieval: `locationRef.child(locItemId).child(senderId).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        let locationId = snapshot.value!["location"] as! String
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
}` but I am still getting errors it would be fantastic if you could help in any way!